# Cakephp 2.0 Pagination with dropdown

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu, pagination, cakephp-2.0

1. I am doing pagination in cakephp. By default there is a list in 
   "$this->Paginator->numbers" but i want some changes in pagination design so i want all pages in dropdwon and current page is selected in dropdown. I successfully get the dropdown by writing the following code but the problem is that when i click on the page it wil not change
   thanks in advance

`
  < select>

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('tag'=>'option'));

</select>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind event onChange to your select element with JS. It should redirect you to selected page. You can see how to construct jump url in cake's [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper). You can also use [this](http://coffeepowered.co.uk/2009/10/quick-and-dirty-dropdown-pagination-in-cakephp/) solution but notice it was written for cake 1.x and will need some changes.